# How to loop through variables without List

Tags: java, android, arrays, variables, methods

How can I loop and modify variables without using hundreds of *if*s?

I currently have the following code:

```
private int one = 5;
private int ten = 9;
private int hundred = 2;
private int thousand = 8;

public void checkBalance() {
    if (one > 1) {
        one *= 0.5;
    }
    if (ten > 1) {
        ten *= 0.5;
    }
    if (hundred > 1) {
        hundred *= 0.5;
    }
    if (thousand > 1) {
        thousand *= 0.5;
    }
}
```

I would however like some way to loop through those variables and do the same thing for each of those. I would not like to use ArrayLists and stuff like that, as I need it to be easy accessible and readible (eg. I call getOne, getHundred)

Comment: With your setup, you can't. Put them in some kind of array/list instead.

Comment: I can't, as I need each variable alone too, that's the problem

Comment: Then you're stuck with the `if`.

Comment: without a list it´s not possible. An Array or an ArrayList or List is easy to access. You can change values, retrieve values, delete values...whatever, it´s possible.

Comment: You could conceivably do this via reflection.  Start by looking up the docs of `java.lang.Class`.  Don't forget to *abandon* that idea when you realize how much more work and mess it's going to be than using appropriate data structures in the first place.  In particular, if you want to access values by name, then consider storing them in one flavor or another of `Map`.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing to do here would be to write a method `int f(int i)` and call it `one = f(one)`. It is, however, likely that the original problem can be solved better than by using variables `one`, ... `thousand` in the first place.

Comment: The answer is a list.  In fact, if you're using this to hold large/exact numbers the answer is use BigDecimal or BigInteger.

Comment: Multiplying an `int` by a `double` only to store the result in an `int`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will look into it!

Comment: @LewBloch only need it to be half, rounded down :)

Comment: So why not `/= 2`?

Comment: I've created an answer based on the advice from @JohnBollinger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I finally got the answer I was looking for!

**Special thanks to [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) for pointing me in the right direction!**

```
private String moneyValues = {"one", "ten", "hundred", "thousand"}

public void calculateBalance() {        
    for (int i = 0; i < moneyValues.length; i++) {
        if (getMoneyValue(moneyValues[i]) > 1) {
            setMoneyValue(moneyValues[i], getMoneyValue(moneyValues[i] * 0.5));
            break;
        }
    }

private int getMoneyValue(String variableName) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = getClass();
        return Integer.parseInt(c.getDeclaredField(variableName).get(this).toString());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

private void setMoneyValue(String variableName, int value) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = getClass();
        c.getDeclaredField(variableName).set(this, value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't want to use `ArrayList` because you want to access each variable by its name e.g. `getOne` or `getHundred`. In this case you should use **`HashMap`**, which solves your looping problem of iterating hundreds of variable as well as variable accessibility.

Here is the example of your problem.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("one", 5);
data.put("ten", 9);
data.put("hundred", 2);
data.put("thousand", 8);
```

> This Solves your looping problem...

```
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(data.keySet());  //Get list of all keys
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {     //iterate through keys
    if (data.get(keys.get(i)) > 1) {
        double temp = data.get(keys.get(i));  
        data.put(keys.get(i), (int)temp * 0.5);  //replace the original value
    }
}
```

> This Solves your variable accessibility problem...

```
System.out.println(data.get("one"));
System.out.println(data.get("ten"));
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP intends to take half your money when you check the balance (down to one of each unit). And I thought my *old* bank was bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way:

```
private int[] numbers = {5, 9, 2, 8};

public void checkBalance() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > 1) {
            numbers[i] *= 0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can get any value this way:

```
System.out.println(numbers[0]); // This will print 5
System.out.println(numbers[1]); // This will print 9
```

Or you can get all values and print them all:

```
for(int n : numbers){
    System.out.println(n); // This will print 5 9 2 8
}
```

**UPDATE:** You can assign the list positions to variables if you want:

```
private int one = numbers[0];
private int ten = numbers[1];
private int hundred = numbers[2];
private int thousand = numbers[3];
```

Comment: As I need to update it multipletimes, assiging the list positions to the variables does not update the variables..

Answer (score -1):

You could use reflection, code generation or just put all your variables in a list in your class. In your example I will prefer last.  I mean create separate variables and a list of thrm at the same time

Comment: Reflection and code generation are both overly complicated and difficult to maintain ideas.

Comment: Thats why I say "In your example I will prefer last."